# Django Jquery Dialog box when specific radio button selected

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-templates, django-views

How would you get the selected radio button, and if it is a specific option display a dialog box with a message to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen for the change event:

```
$('#my-select-id').change(function(e){
    if(e.target.value === 'special') {
        displayDialog();
    }
});
```

Comment: how about if you select a certain radio button?

Comment: That's exactly what nathanjosiah has answered.